# How do I hide Discovery page only in search result page?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, user-experience, dspace

Usually with the discovery is this:

[image]

I want to hide Discover page only on the search results page or any other page specifies? its possible?

I used CSS to hide in this example:

[image]

My discovery.xml file :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:i18n="http://apache.org/cocoon/i18n/2.1"
    xmlns:dri="http://di.tamu.edu/DRI/1.0/"
    xmlns:mets="http://www.loc.gov/METS/"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/TR/xlink/"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:dim="http://www.dspace.org/xmlns/dspace/dim"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="i18n dri mets xlink xsl dim xhtml mods dc">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>


        <xsl:template match="dri:options">


        <xsl:if test="$request-uri != ''">


            <div id="navigation">

                <span class="logoEducapes">Logo Educapes</span>

                <span class="logoCapes">Logo Capes</span>

                <aside>

                    <div id="ds-options">


                        <xsl:apply-templates/>              

                        <!-- DS-984 Add RSS Links to Options Box -->


                <xsl:if test="count(/dri:document/dri:meta/dri:pageMeta/dri:metadata[@element='feed']) != 0">

                    <nav>

                        <h2 id="ds-feed-option-head" class="ds-option-set-head">

                            <i18n:text>xmlui.feed.header</i18n:text>

                        </h2>





                    <div class="menu" style="display:none;">


                        <div id="ds-feed-option" class="ds-option-set">

                            <ul>

                                <xsl:call-template name="addRSSLinks"/>


                            </ul>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </nav>

                </xsl:if>


                </div>

                    <h2 class="h2h"><p class="title">CENTRAL DE<br/><i18n:text>xmlui.central.contents</i18n:text></p></h2>
                        <ul class="lista-padrao3">
                            <li>
                                <a href="/xmlui/discover?filtertype=type&amp;filter_relational_operator=equals&amp;filter=vídeo">
                                    <span class="s1"></span><p class="ppar2"><i18n:text>xmlui.central.type.video</i18n:text></p>
                                </a>
                            </li>


                            <li>
                                <a href="/xmlui/discover?filtertype=type&amp;filter_relational_operator=equals&amp;filter=áudio">
                                    <span class="s2"></span><p class="ppar2"><i18n:text>xmlui.central.type.audio</i18n:text></p>
                                </a>
                            </li>


                            <li>
                                <a href="/xmlui/discover?filtertype=type&amp;filter_relational_operator=equals&amp;filter=imagem">
                                    <span class="s3"></span><p class="ppar2"><i18n:text>xmlui.central.type.imagem</i18n:text></p>
                                </a>
                            </li>


                            <li>
                                <a href="/xmlui/discover?filtertype=type&amp;filter_relational_operator=equals&amp;filter=texto">
                                    <span class="s4"></span><p class="ppar2"><i18n:text>xmlui.central.type.texto</i18n:text></p>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="/xmlui/discover?filtertype=type&amp;filter_relational_operator=equals&amp;filter=outro">
                                    <span class="s5"></span><p class="ppar2"><i18n:text>xmlui.central.type.other</i18n:text></p>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
            </aside>

        </div>







        </xsl:if>



    </xsl:template>

    <!--give nested navigation list the class sublist-->
  <xsl:template match="dri:options/dri:list/dri:list" priority="3" mode="nested">


        <li>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="dri:head" mode="nested"/>
            <ul class="ds-simple-list sublist">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="dri:item" mode="nested"/>

            </ul>

        </li>





    </xsl:template>


    <!-- Add each RSS feed from meta to a list -->
    <xsl:template name="addRSSLinks">

        <xsl:for-each select="/dri:document/dri:meta/dri:pageMeta/dri:metadata[@element='feed']">

            <li>

            <a>
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <xsl:attribute name="style">
                        <xsl:text>background: url(</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$context-path"/>
                        <xsl:text>/static/icons/feed.png) no-repeat</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <xsl:choose>

                        <xsl:when test="contains(., 'rss_1.0')">
                            <xsl:text>RSS 1.0</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="contains(., 'rss_2.0')">
                            <xsl:text>RSS 2.0</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="contains(., 'atom_1.0')">
                            <xsl:text>Atom</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@qualifier"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>

                    </xsl:choose>

                </a>

            </li>

        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Quick patch to remove empty lists from options -->
    <xsl:template match="dri:options//dri:list[count(child::*)=0]" priority="5" mode="nested">
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="dri:options//dri:list[count(child::*)=0]" priority="5">
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I was thinking of some way to restrict through the URL, but got no result yet.

Comment: The images are fine, but to help you we should see your code

Comment: Sorry. Would be my discovery.xml file?

Comment: This question is very confusing.  The question is not likely to make sense to reviewers who are unfamiliar with DSpace.  You have labeled your code sample as discovery.xml but the sample code is xslt.  I have some recommendations that might be helpful to your question.  I recommend that you carefully edit your question.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The discovery.xml file contains 2 configurations.  One configuration for collections and another for the "home page".

https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace/config/spring/api/discovery.xml#L42-L46

If you edit the facet list for the "home page", you may be able to remove the unwanted facets from the landing page and search results page.

https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace/config/spring/api/discovery.xml#L204-L207